# Cannot register new System Center 2012 Service Manager Data Warehouse after Service Manager database move

Tags: windows, system-center, scsm-2012

I recently migrated a customer from a 3 server SCSM topology to a 5 server SCSM topology and I am now having an issue registering the Data Warehouse Management Server with the Service Manager Management Server.

All servers run Windows Server 2012 except for SCSM3, which run 2008 R2 SP1.

---

### Original Configuration

**SCSM1**

- Service Manager Management Server 2012 SP1 UR2
- SQL Server 2012 with ServiceManager  and SharePoint Foundation 2010 (for SSP) databases

**SCSM2**

- Service Manager Data Warehouse Management Server 2012 SP1 UR2
- SQL Server 2012 with all 5 data warehouse databases on it, as well as SSRS and SSAS.

**SCSM3**

- SharePoint Foundation 2010 SP1
- Service Manager 2012 SP1 UR2 Web Content Server
- Service Manager 2012 SP1 UR2 SharePoint Web Parts

---

### Revised Configuration

**SCSM1**

- Service Manager Management Server 2012 SP1 UR2

**SCSM2**

- Service Manager Data Warehouse Management Server 2012 SP1 (You cannot install UR2 until the DW has been registered an MPSync has run successfully multiple times)

**SCSM3**

- SharePoint Foundation 2010 SP2
- Service Manager 2012 SP1 UR2 Web Content Server
- Service Manager 2012 SP1 UR2 SharePoint Web Parts

**SCSM4**

- SQL Server 2012 with ServiceManager  and SharePoint Foundation 2010 (for SSP) databases

**SCSM5**

- SQL Server 2012 with all 5 data warehouse databases on it, as well as SSRS and SSAS. SSRS was configured with the proper manual configuration detailed here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh519664.aspx

---

### Migration Steps

The customer was hitting performance issues which are common when SQL is located on a management server, so I did the following:

1. Stand up two new servers that will function as dedicated SQL Servers.
2. Unregister the Data Warehouse (the install was relatively new, so no DW data retention was necessary)
3. [Follow this TechNet blog post to move the ServiceManager database to a new server](http://blogs.technet.com/b/servicemanager/archive/2012/04/22/moving-the-service-manager-and-dw-databases.aspx)
4. Uninstall SharePoint Foundation and the WCS from SCSM3
5. Uninstall SQL Server from SCSM1
6. Uninstall the Data Warehouse Management Server from SCSM2
7. Uninstall SQL Server from SCSM2
8. Reinstall the Self-Service Portal on SCSM3 using the new database server for SharePoint databases.
9. Reinstall the Data Warehouse Management Server on SCSM2 specifying the new database server during the install. I've tried this using both the old DW Management Group's name and a new Management Group name.

---

This all went fine (including the Data Warehouse installation), but when I go to register the new Data Warehouse with the Service Manager Management Server, I get the following error:

> The Data Access Service is either not running or not yet initialized

A similar error is thrown when trying to register the DW via PowerShell using `Register-SCDWSource`

The service (and all other System Center Services) are indeed running on all servers that they should be running on. Service Manager itself is working fine after the database migration. The Self-Service Portal is functioning properly as well.

There are no rows in the `dbo.MT_Microsoft$SystemCenter$ResourceAccessLayer$DwSdkResourceStore` table, as the old Data Warehouse was successfully unregistered, so truncating this table won't resolve the issue.

What I've tried based on TechNet article and forum posts:

- Restart System Center services on all servers.
- Verify that my account in in the Built-In\Administrators group on all servers.
- Verified that my account is in the Service Manager administrators group.
- Verified that the proper SPNs for the Data Access Service are registered manually.
- Disabled anti-virus temporarily on each server.
- Telnet to port 5724 works between all servers and workstations in the environment.

---

Does anyone know what else could be causing this?

Comment: Im having the same issue.  Did you wind up figuring out what the cause was?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old posting, but it's a situation I found myself in recently under the same circumstances. The problem I had was self-inflicted, when you go through the process of updating all the SCSM DB table references to the old servers and point them to the new servers, all of them point to the new SQL server except the dbo. MT_Microsoft$SystemCenter$ResourceAccessLayer$SdkResourceStore which points to the primary management server. I accidentally set that to the new SQL server, hence the DW registration error about the data access service not running. Once I found and fixed the problem, DW registration worked.